# Need help to convert following html to csv with meta tags of html

Tags: xml, xslt, special-characters, transform

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Headline</title>
<meta name="targetUrl" value="xyz.html?sym=abc"/>
<meta name="summary" value="A & B"/>
</head>
<body>
abc abc, pqr, xyz, rst tsd, prrrr, qqqqqqq, oooooo, opop opop, rtrttrt rtrtrtrt
</body>
</html>
```

The body tag should be changed to csv so the output should be like this :

abc abc, pqr, xyz, rst tsd, prrrr, qqqqqqq, oooooo, opop opop, rtrttrt rtrtrtrt

if i try @Jim's solution

parsing exception occurs for meta tags as they have special characters

Comment: That is not a well formed XML document. Before XSLT processing you would need to use some HTML parser that builds a DOM instance capable of been the input for your XSLT processor. Depending on your enviroment, that would be probably a duplicated question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT1 solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="body"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that since your input contains a newline before and after the data, it will be written to the output as well, resulting in a blank first and lasst line.

Comment: It could be shorter: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:template match="head"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: Thanks Jim for the answer, really appreciate it.

Comment: I have meta tags with special characters in the html and I want to ignore by using the above xsl @Jim, @Alejandro is it possible to skip meta tags, would appreciate if I can get an example xsl achieving this.