# How to escape special characters when transforming html to text using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, special-characters

Sample html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Headline</title>
    <meta name="targetUrl" value="xyz.html?sym=abc"/>
    <meta name="summary" value="A & B"/>
</head>
    <body>
        abc abc, pqr, xyz, rst tsd, prrrr, qqqqqqq, oooooo, opop opop, rtrttrt rtrtrtrt
    </body>
</html>
```

This is just an sample html and it could be any random special chracters and I dont have access to htmls.
I tried using following xsl but it doesnt work

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="xsl:text"/>
<xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>
<xsl:variable name="fieldNames" select="'yes'"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:if test="$fieldNames = 'yes'">
                        <xsl:text>title</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                        <xsl:text>targetURL</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                        <xsl:text>summary-r</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                        <xsl:text>body</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(html/head/title)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="html/head/meta[@name='targetURL']/@value" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="html/head/meta[@name='summary-r']/@value" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(html/body)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not different from [Need help to convert following html to csv with meta tags of html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807632/need-help-to-convert-following-html-to-csv-with-meta-tags-of-html)

Comment: @Alejandro I m trying this all in a shell script coz I need to migrate those htmls to csv and do some logic i tries using perl script to convert to a valid xml format but no luck yet. My question is : Is there a way where I can directly convert html/XML to csv/text via xsl having special characters?

Comment: As I wrote you before, your input document is not a well formed XML document (because those characters). You need an HTML parser wich can built a DOM that your XSLT processor could use as input tree. Thus you should be asking **what are the HTML parsers** aviable for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT will only work on XML input, not on HTML. So you need to start by running an HTML to XML conversion before you do the XSLT transformation. There are plenty of tools to do this, e.g. John Cowan's TagSoup.